# how to pass a string in an Onclick event

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm trying to add an anchor automatically and this is what i've done

```
" <a  id='" + x.NomFic + "' onclick='TransfererFica( " +x.Idtran +"  ,  "+ x.NumVdr + "  , '" + x.NomFic + "' )';   </a>"
```

but the problem that  `x.NomFic` is a string so when i click on the anchor it raises an error, so my question is how can i pass a param string , i've tried to put an integer just to check if my code works and it did, and when i change `x.NomFic` to accept string the code didn't work, any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a escape character "\" in your code

```
" <a  id='" + x.NomFic + "' onclick='TransfererFica( " + x.Idtran + "  ,  " 
       + x.NumVdr + "  , \"" + x.NomFic + "\" )';   </a>"
```

More reading about escape character

https://csharpindepth.com/articles/Strings

Comment: @user1187282 you can refer this for your future reference https://csharpindepth.com/articles/Strings